# Train accuracy drops in some epochs

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, resnet

I'm training a ResNet (CIFAR-10 dataset) and train accuracy is mostly (in 95% epochs) increasing, but sometimes it drops 5-10% and then it starts increasing again.

Here is an example:

```
Epoch 45/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 50s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0323 - acc: 0.9948 - val_loss: 1.6562 - val_acc: 0.7404
Epoch 46/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 52s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0371 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 1.6526 - val_acc: 0.7448
Epoch 47/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 50s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0266 - acc: 0.9955 - val_loss: 1.6925 - val_acc: 0.7426
Epoch 48/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 50s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0353 - acc: 0.9940 - val_loss: 2.2682 - val_acc: 0.6496
Epoch 49/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 50s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6391 - acc: 0.4862 - val_loss: 1.2524 - val_acc: 0.5659
Epoch 50/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 52s 1ms/step - loss: 0.9220 - acc: 0.6830 - val_loss: 0.9726 - val_acc: 0.6738
Epoch 51/100
40000/40000 [==============================] - 51s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5453 - acc: 0.8165 - val_loss: 1.0232 - val_acc: 0.6963
```

I've quit execution after this, but this was my second run and in first, same thing happened and after some time it got back to 99%.

Batch is 128 so I guess this is not a problem. I haven't change learning rate or any other Adam parameters, but I guess that's also not an issue since accuracy is increasing most of the time.

So, why are those sudden drops happening?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to answer _why_, but in my experience of training NNs and from what I've read, it seems this is a standard and expected thing to happen. In fact, if you keep training over an even larger number of epochs, the accuracy will likely gradually decrease, and it's about finding that "sweet spot" between dips being expected noise and being a downwards trend. I believe there's no definite linear correlation between epochs and accuracy, but again I don't know the technical reason why.

Comment: Yes, this is something I've read also, but as far as I understood this was the problem with very deep networks without residual blocks and accuracy drop was constant -- once accuracy started to drop, it never increased. Also, since this is a ResNet (and a shallow one, ResNet50), I would assume this should not be a problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since training and validation loss and accuracy all increase it looks like your optimization algorithm has temporarily overshot the downhill part of the loss function that it was trying to follow.

Remember gradient descent and related methods calculate the gradient at a point and then use that (and sometimes some additional data) to guess the direction and distance to move. This is not always perfect and sometimes it will go too far and end up further uphill again.

If your learning rate is aggressive you will see this every now and then, but you might still converge faster than with a smaller learning rate. You can experiment with different learning rates, but I would not be concerned unless your loss starts to diverge.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct since you've confirmed what I've thought. I guess something smarter than having the same learning rate could improve performance since drop happens when network reaches high accuracy where it should start to explore surroundings with smaller steps.

Also, I'm not sure if simple case of a gradient descent is completely applicable here since functions that deep NN are optimizing have more sadle-like shapes, but, as I've said above, learning rate decay should help in later stages of a training